# How can I remove this Scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

[image: This is automatically visible, pls help me disable it]

This is automatically visible, pls help me disable it! 
Thanks so much!

Src: https://github.com/noname181/htmlcss

Comment: can you share your code...

Comment: Share the URL or post the code which creates that output! :)

Comment: You can set `overflow: hidden` on the element.

Comment: I just share my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `overflow:auto` css property from `#container` id

```
#container 
{
 width: 980px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just decrease the size of the width and change the height of the boxes in order to make it less navigable and more restricted to a page.

One of the things you can do:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing :border-box;
}
```